# Configure mysimpleads with CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I am having a problem integrating mysimlead application with CakePHP. this application is in the another directory on server root and I want to include it in my CakePHP app using PHP scripts . please help . if I use simple PHP file on webroot. it works. but when I use it in controller it doesn't work. 
Here is the script I am using

```
chdir("/home/abc/def/myads");
include_once("/home/abc/def/myads/mysimpleads.php");
show_ad_group(2);
```

Here is my CakePHP app path

```
home/abc/mysite
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the PHP Remote Read ad code and assign the results to a variable. This also looks like v1 of mySimpleAds, you might want to upgrade to v2.